# How do I format the data prettier with nice format?

Tags: javascript, html

We receive data from our upstream source system with the format as provided below ( script section).. When I use the pre tag to display in our web page, the formatting does seem to be off due to the extra "\t" or"\r" .

Here is the source code,

```
<html>
<body>

<pre id="div">
</pre>
<script>
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML=
`Group Name:    Test GROUP BUSINESS - SAA\r\nPRODUCT:ABC\t\tPRIME  CTR: Denver\r\nOPTIONAL NAME: \t\t\tPLATINUM GROUP: Y\r\NEWRK: ABC/KLF\r\n\r\SA STATE:    
\AA\t\t\tET STATE:   CO\r\SA  MANDATE:  N/A\t\tET MANDATES: N/A\t\\t\r\n\r\nABCAA STATUS:\t\t\GRANDF\r\n\t\t\t\tNETWORK:\t\tNON-NEWRK:\r\nCALENDAR YEAR  
 MAX:\t\tN/A\t  \t\tN/A\r\nLIFE MAX:\t\t\t\t  $1000  (COMBINED)        \t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\tNEWRK:\t\tNON-NEWRK:\r\nTESTIN
 \t\t\t100%\t\t\t80%\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\rNEWRK:\t\t NON-NEWRK:\r\nMY MONEY:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\nCALENDAR YEAR\t\t\t\r\n   
 IND:\t\t\tNone\t\t\GRP\t\t\t$1000\r\n   CROSS ACCUM?\t\t\tN/A`
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

My requirement is to
a) Need to "bold" the text before ":"
b) display it in a table format with border for each cell ( like below). A script formatting . Is it possible ?. ANy expertise thoughts ?

```
| **Group Name: **  Test Group               |
| -------- ----------------------------------|
| **Product:** ABC  |**Prime CTR:** Denver   |
| -------- ----------------------------------|
| **Optional Name:** | **Platinum Group: ** Y|
```

I tried using table as below. But I am getting only the outer border. Also I don't know how to bold the text before ":".

```
<table id = 'div' border = 1>
       </table>
```

Comment: Do you have any control over whatever is sending the string you're injecting? The reason I'm asking - it would be much easier to parse if you were to receive it as a JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately, no - they don't do formatting changes, since  the source system is consumed by different downstream applications, so they don't change just for our application.

Comment: Sorry to your other question, yes we receive the data as "JSON" to our application. thank you..

Comment: More info is needed. 1) Are the first three lines from the received text the only thing you need, or do you need all of it? 2) Does your first row of your example table have a `colspan=2`? 3) `Optional name` is empty. Is that always the case? 4) Are the labels (`Group name`, `Product`, etc) and the structure (order of rows received) always the same? Depending on your answers to this, I (or someone else on SO) would be able to offer a suggestion, or a solution. I'd first start with a regex replacement of empty lines - `\n(\s+\n|\n)` would be replaced with this `\n`.

Comment: thanks, all are dynamic data and that's the challenge. It's possible I wouldn't receive the first line itself. One question -> Is it possible to draw a horizontal line based on the "\n" ?.. As it's common for new line ..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work for you. The solution makes some assumptions (it's alright to remove the empty lines, it's alright to remove the extra tab characters - this one's in the comments at the moment - it's alright to use them as table data delimiters, etc), and is presented in a somewhat suboptimal way, to make it easier to follow.

Expand and run the following snippet to see what it does.

```js
var originalText = `Group Name:    Test GROUP BUSINESS - SAA

PRODUCT:ABC     PRIME  CTR: Denver

OPTIONAL NAME:          PLATINUM GROUP: Y
NEWRK: ABC/KLF


SA STATE:    
AA          ET STATE:   CO
SA  MANDATE:  N/A       ET MANDATES: N/A    \t



ABCAA STATUS:       GRANDF

                NETWORK:        NON-NEWRK:

CALENDAR YEAR  
 MAX:       N/A         N/A

LIFE MAX:                 $1000  (COMBINED)         

                                
            NEWRK:      NON-NEWRK:

TESTIN
            100%            80%

                            

                                

NEWRK:       NON-NEWRK:

MY MONEY:                               

CALENDAR YEAR           

   
 IND:           None        GRP         $1000

   CROSS ACCUM?         N/A `;
// find the newline character, followed either by:
// 1. multiple spaces or tabs, which ar followed by a newline,
// followed by multiple spaces or tabs
// or
// 2. another newline, followed by multiple spaces or tabs
// or
// 3. multiple spaces
var pattern = /\n(\s+\n\s+|\n\s+|\s+)/gm;
var cleanText = originalText.replace(pattern,"\n"); // remove extra empty lines

// remove the comment from the following line, if you need to remove the extra tabs
// cleanText = cleanText.replace(/\t+/gm,"\t"); // replace extra tabs with single tab
// console.log(cleanText); // for debugging purposes, remove the comment if needed

// let's explode the cleanText by \n
var lines = cleanText.split("\n");
// let's see what we have now
// console.log(lines); // for debugging purposes, remove the comment if needed

// let's loop through individual lines, and fill a helper array
var tableRows = [];
var i;
for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    // we are, perhaps incorrectly, assuming the \t character is
    // acting as a separator / table data delimiter
    var singleLine = lines[i].trim().split("\t");
    // console.log(singleLine); // for debugging purposes, remove the comment if needed
    tableRows.push(singleLine);
}

// let's see what's the largest td count
var maxTds = Math.max(...tableRows.map(i => i.length))

// let's go back to our array of rows, and prepare our HTML text
var tableContents = "";
for(i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    // how many empty tds do we need to add?
    var diff = maxTds - tableRows[i].length;
    
    // add the missing td, so that our table doesn't look weird
    for(var tds = 0; tds < diff; tds++) {
        tableRows[i].push('');
    }
    
    tableContents += "<tr>";
    for(var j = 0; j < tableRows[i].length; j++) {
        tableContents += "<td>";
        
        var tableData = tableRows[i][j].trim();
        // check if the current word group contains :
        // if it does, wrap it inside <strong></strong>
        if(tableData.indexOf(":") >=0) {
            tableData = "<strong>" + tableData.substring(0,tableData.indexOf(":")+1) + "</strong>";
        }
        
        tableContents += tableData + "</td>"
    }
    tableContents += "</tr>";
}

tableContents = "<table><tbody>" + tableContents + "</tbody></table>";

document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHTML = tableContents;
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #bababa;
  padding: 3px;
  min-width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableContainer"></div>
```